# Makefile problem

Tags: graphics

I am having problems with compiling EPS images, I don’t know whether it is a problem with my `makefile` or not. When I am compiling a document with EPS images, it takes like 4 minutes to compile them, how can I overcome that? Is it a `makefile` problem? If it is can someone help me with a working example? Or could you help me with a template with a `makefile` and a sample image included? I just don't know whether EPS is becoming obsolete but it is taking ages to be compiled.

Comment: Does the compilation take 4 minutes without the makefile as well? How do you compile the file, what are the steps in the makefile.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With no MWE, this is 'unclear'.